# Add markerwater in Android using Glide

Tags: android, watermark, android-glide, android-paint

I have the code to add a bitmap on imageview:

```
try {
        Glide.with(imagen.getContext())
                .load(item.getIdImagen())
                .into(imagen);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
```

I also have the code that would add the watermark:

```
public Bitmap applyWaterMarkEffect(Bitmap src, String watermark, int x, int y, int color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, x, y, paint);

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that I do not know how to combine them to show everything together. Should I get the image(bitmap) to pass it as a parameter? In that case, how do I get it?

Thanks!

Comment: How you did it can exactly show the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make your own [custom transformation](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-custom-transformation)

You get the original bitmap in your transformation class, you add the watermark and return the bitmap with the watermark.

Than you could simply do

```
Glide  
    .with(context)
    .load(someUrl)
    .bitmapTransform(new WatermarkTransformation(context))
    .into(imageView);
```